# Need Help In Sql like query

Tags: mysql, sql

| ID | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | lastname | John Carter Samules |
| 2 | lastname | Gayel Carter Cleve |
| 3 | lastname | leve Carter Husan |
| 4 | lastname | Gyan Carter eve |

I want like query which fetch `meta_value` for middle name `carter`.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please show us what you have tried, what does not work, and do not forget to format the code you post. Check out the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: A bit unclear question, you mean select * from table where meta_value like '% Carter %'   (A space before and after ensures middle name.)

Comment: its select * from table where meta_key='lastname' AND meta_value like '% Carter %'                                                                                                                   But i'm not sure like works in this case, usually i  see like works if value start and end with specific string.

Comment: If my answer helped you, not forget to accept It as correct answer. Good luck. Updated my answer with explaining about wild cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you need something like that:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable
WHERE meta_value LIKE '% carter %'
```

This will work for you, because added wildcard `%` before and after word `carter`. This means, that no care what is before and after `carter`, It will select all results where is middle name `carter`

More info about **LIKE** and **WILDCARDS** can be found  [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)